# css - what does a.extra indicate?

Tags: css

I'm looking at a css template that includes `.myClass a.extra{...}` and .myClass `a.extra:hover{...}`  What does the "extra" mean?

Comment: thanks to everyone for contributing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extra` is the name of a class.

Since you have:

```
.myClass a.extra{...}
```

that rule is applying to all the `a` elements with the `extra` class which are descendants of an element with the `myClass` class.

Comment: ah!  so extra is not some standard element of css or html.  The css template I'm using must be paired with an html file that uses class extra in an `a href`?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `a.extra` indicates an anchor tag with a class name of 'extra'.

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="extra"> Extra link! </a>
```

Chained selectors mean that both belong to the same element. So if I wanted to select a div with the id of "foo" and the class of "bar", I could define the rule in my CSS like so:

```
div#foo.bar {
  /* disco */
}
```

Whereas using a space to separate (like in your example) would define a child attribute selector:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myClass a.extra {
  /* disco */
}
</style>

<div class="myClass">
  <a href="#" class="extra"> disco </a>
</div>
```

Check out more attribute selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's the class of the anchor.  When the css says something like `a.extra`, it refers to an `<a>` element in html like this:

```
<a class="extra">Contents</a>
```

This is an example of a more general concept: `x.y` refers to any element `<x class="y">`.

Answer (score 1):

The a.extra means any anchor element with a class of "extra".

The entire line indicates:

Any anchor element with a class of "extra" that resides under any elements with a class of "myClass"